# Is there a way to convert a string in the format of a matrix path into a numeric array?

Tags: r

I am trying to pass the string version of a matrix path containing numeric data into a function.

I've tried to use `noquote()` to strip the quotations as well as `as.numeric()` to convert its class. But the later only returns NA by coercion.

The following is an example of the normal way and the way I wish for it to work for:

```r
df = as.data.frame(matrix(rexp(25, rate = 0.01), 5)) # Random matrix
colnames(df) = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e") # Giving it column names
df # Looks like this
dens_df_a.WORKS = density.default(df$a) # Making a density object
plot(dens_df_a.WORKS) # Plotting it nice and fresh
###   This works!   ###

#------------------------------------------------------------

matrix_path = noquote("df$a") # Assigning the same matrix path with no string quotes
dens_df_a.FAILS = density.default(matrix_path) # Doesn't create density object this time
###   This messes up :(  ###
```

To re-phrase my question, how can I 'activate' `matrix_path` in the code given so that it works as the first half does?

Instead of working, I get the error "argument 'x' must be numeric" (which is not news).

This might seem unnecessary to try and attempt but I want to achieve this on a large scale, not for one path. So I'm not really planning on hard coding 50 paths.

Comment: you can use `eval(parse(...`, `dens_df_a.FAILS = density.default(eval(parse(text = matrix_path))) `

Comment: Yep like @RonakShah said, `matrix_path = eval(parse(text = "df$a")); density.default(matrix_path);`